# sqlite in android using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I created an application for rails. Initially it is running well. Now i am trying to add an extra column to the database. In the database the additional column is not getting updated however I try. I used the onUpgrade() method and altered table but it didnt work. I tried to change the column in sqlite database browser it was updated there but i dont know how to replicate it back into the front end code I tried all the possibilities to that . Now that I created a new project and tried to insert that column again. I couldnt find out the package name in "data/data". Please could anybody tell me why i coulnt find the database and why am i unable to add new column to the database. Please be polite and patient coz I am a beginner. Thanks in advance

Comment: completely uninstall the app from the device and clean the project. Try now.

Comment: whenever u update a column in SQLite table changes reflects only after reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 2):

Actually,when you use the onUpgrade() method you haven't change the database version code.

when you create SQLiteOpenHandler class object then  you have to pass a database version code in it. when you pass a new version code in the constructor of SQLiteOpenHandler class then onUpgrade() method is called.

i.e.

```
SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

previously if you pass version = 1 then you have to pass a new version code in it i.e 2 or 3 or some new integer value then your onUpgrade() method is called and it will solve your problem.

For more details you can go throught this [link](http://dilipdevelopment.blogspot.in/2012/05/creeate-database-in-android-using.html)

and Another issue you have raised that you haven't found package name in data/data folder
please check that the package name of your new project will be the same as your previous one.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Refer this below link

    http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
    -----------------------------------------------------------
```

### http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

```
Essential Block of the code in this part..




package de.vogella.android.sqlite.first;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class CommentsDataSource {

  // Database fields
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
  private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
      MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT };

  public CommentsDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }

  public Comment createComment(String comment) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);
    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null,
        values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
        allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
        null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Comment newComment = cursorToComment(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newComment;
  }

  public void deleteComment(Comment comment) {
    long id = comment.getId();
    System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
    database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
        + " = " + id, null);
  }

  public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
        allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
      comments.add(comment);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return comments;
  }

  private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
    return comment;
  }
}
```